# Arduino Sketch is not Uploading into Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino

I am trying to upload a sketch into Arduino Mega 2560, but it's not uploading. It's showing an error message-

```
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0xbf != 0x06
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

[image: Error message while uploading sketch into Arduino Mega 2560]

It was just working fine since I used it last time. Suddenly it has just stopped working.

Comment: You could take a look at this http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17762/avrdude-verification-error-first-mismatch-at-byte-0x0000-0x00-0x16-using

Comment: I tried that, but still facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

i would check that avrdude was able to write any bytes of the flash section:

- read current flash:

  ```
  avrdude  -c arduino -p atmega2560 -P /dev/arduino -b 57600 -U flash:r:flash.0.bin:r
  ```
- write something(different) into it

  ```
  avrdude  -c arduino -p atmega2560 -P /dev/arduino -b 57600 -U flash:w:something.hex:i
  ```
- read it back

  ```
  avrdude  -c arduino -p atmega2560 -P /dev/arduino -b 57600 -U flash:r:flash.2.bin:r
  ```
- check if anything have changed:

  ```
  md5sum flash*
  ```

  - if the 2 sums are the same...avrdude can't change the fw inside the device...there are lockbits which may prevent it...because lockbits can't be turned back on: in this case you should write a new bootloader into the device using another arduino or a stock avrisp...(dont worry...it's easy)
  - if the sums are different...and the board is apparently running the firmware you have loaded...something inside the arduino ide is messed up

hope this helps ;)

Comment: How can I write a new bootloader?

Comment: i think you may have forgotten to change :r: to :w: in the command for write something(different) into it